# Group rows with same column value

Tags: php, arrays, merge, grouping

I have a PHP array which has several different fields. For some of the rows id and name is the same and the rest of data is different.

I want to display the data in an HTML table without listing the duplicated data more than once. I realize that I can use colspan/rowspan to merge the table cells, but I'm not sure how to do counts/sums based on the matching values.

Below is how my table looks like :

```
Id      Name     value1      value2       value3
2312     ABC     test        test2         test3   
2312     ABC     XYz          122           211
2455     XYZ     val11        val2          val3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dont use the same id for multiple element. id must be unique

Comment: As far as I can see the ids in this case are unique (to be clear, we're not talking about HTML ids here). His primary key spans the id-name fields (we might not be in the database at this point, but the integrity of his data is sound).

Comment: The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

Comment: If you're using a RDBMS, I think you should address the problem in the query. Anymay colspan/rospan is not what you need here, deleting extra rows and modifying the first would suffice.

Comment: @Registered User The ids in this question are **not** HTML ids.

Comment: I think GROUP BY command is usefull

Comment: Matt is right . i am not talking about HTML ids here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you to create a new multidimensional array and merge the arrays that have the same ID ... the rest will be easy. Take a look at the example I've made

```
<?
 $init_array = array(
  array('id'=>2312, 'name'=>'ABC', 'value1'=>'asda', 'value2'=>'sdf', 'value3'=>'dfg'),
  array('id'=>2312, 'name'=>'ABC', 'value1'=>'asd', 'value2'=>'fgd', 'value3'=>'ret'),
  array('id'=>2455, 'name'=>'XYZ', 'value1'=>'sdgg', 'value2'=>'rew', 'value3'=>'gdg'),
 );
 $formatted_array = array();

 foreach( $init_array as $element ) {
  $formatted_array[ $element['id'] ][] = $element;
 }
?>

<table border="2">
 <? foreach($formatted_array as $row ): ?>
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['id']?></td>
     <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['name']?></td>
     <? foreach( $row as $value ): ?>
      <td><?=$value['value1']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value2']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value3']?></td>
      </tr><tr>
     <? endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
 <? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

the example in [CodePad](http://codepad.org/oSUN6dAo)

Answer (score 1):

The point is that use a 2-dimension array to store the size(rowspan) value of each cell, and if we don't need a cell, the size of it is zero.

And here's a sample code. You may need to sort your array first.

```
<?php
$rows = array(
    array(2312, 'ABC', 'asda', 'sdf', 'dfg'),
    array(2312, 'ABCD', 'asd', 'fgd', 'ret'),
    array(2313, 'ABCD', 'asd', 'fgd', 'ret'),
    array(2455, 'XYZ', 'sdgg', 'rew', 'gdg'),
);

function try_merge_col( &$rows, &$trs, &$tr, $row_i, $col_i )
{
    $row = $rows[$row_i];
    $old = $rows[$row_i-1];
    if( $row[$col_i] == $old[$col_i] )
    {
        $tr[$col_i]=0; //throw it
        for( $k = $row_i-1; $k>=0; $k-- ) //from down to up
        {
            if( $trs[$k][$col_i] > 0 ) { //do merge
                $trs[$k][$col_i]++;
                break;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}   

function get_table( $rows )
{
    $ret = "";
    $trs = array(
        array(1,1,1,1,1)
        ); //used to store cell size
    $last_row = null;
    for( $i = 1; $i < count($rows); $i++ )
    {
        $this_tr = array(1,1,1,1,1);
        try_merge_col( $rows, $trs, $this_tr, $i, 0 ); //id
        try_merge_col( $rows, $trs, $this_tr, $i, 1 ); //name
        array_push( $trs, $this_tr );
    }   
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++ )
    {
        $tr = $trs[$i];
        $ret .= "<tr>";
        for( $j=0 ; $j<5 ; $j++ )
        {
            if( $tr[$j] >= 1 )
            {
                if( $tr[$j] > 1 ) $ret .= "<td rowspan=\"".$tr[$j]."\">";
                else $ret .= "<td>";   
                $ret .= $rows[$i][$j]; 
                $ret .= "</td>";
            }   
        }   
        $ret .= "</tr>";
    }   
    return $ret;
}   

echo get_table( $rows );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) the array.

Save ID and name each time, then at the beginning of each row, check if the ID & name are identical to last one. If they are - merge the rows.

Comment: I'm sure dthat the id and name are related so you should verify just one of it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to just run a for loop with each row & column in consideration.

Some rough psuedo-code:

```
idArray = [];
idVal_Dict = {};

for col in table{ // Run through each Column ..
    if col == 1{
        for id in col1{
            if ! id == 1{ // If we're on the first column ..
                idArray.append(id.value()); // append id value ..
            }
        }
    }else{
        for val in col{ // For Other columns, find the matching ID & store to a dictionary ..
            idVal_Dict[val.value()] = idArray[val];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know what you are planing to show in a table different data with same Id in two rows. But I think you should merge values in your php codes (not in the view) then send them to the view as clear data. So you can check for equal ID values and get the sum of them before merging.

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's if else statement to check the count of IDs and then apply the foreach loop to display the info. I think it should work that way. You use count as

```
count($data[id]);
```